# setting and returning values using a single class

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to use the same class to set and return the user-inputs.

```
login(user= 'abc', passwd = 'xyz') # set the username and password
x, y = login()   # return the current username and password
```

Is this possible using the same class or is it possible only with 2 distinct classes?

This is what I have tried:

```
class login:
    def __init__(self, user=None, passwd=None):
        self.username = user
        self.password = passwd
        self.myval= self.username + ' ' + self.password  

    def xlim(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args and not kwargs:
            return self.get_xlim()
        ret = self.set_xlim(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return ret

    def get_xlim(self):
        return self.myval

    def set_xlim(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #self.username = self.kwargs['user']
        return self.username
```

I have also tried `repr` but it seems to insisting on returning a string while I need tuple.

Comment: Why do you want a constructor (`__init__`)  to return something else than the instance?

Comment: @LutzHorn `__init__` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @DeepSpace True. Let me rephrase: Why does the OP want to use a constructor as an instance method?

Comment: xlim method of matplotlib.pyplot allows the user to set xmin and xmax values and if you call xlim() then it simply returns the same. I want similar functionality to be used in my class.

Comment: @shantanuo It's an instance method, not the `__init__` method which is what you are showing in your use case.

Comment: DeepSpace's answer is correct. But can someone confirm that there is no way to make it work with instance attributes?

Answer (score 2):

A. You don't need a class.

B. If you really want a class:

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password


login_details = Login(user='a', password='b')

print(login_details.user)
>> 'a'
print(login_details.password)
>> 'b'
```

**EDIT** OP mentioned they want a tuple:

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def as_tuple(self):
        return self.user, self.password

login_details = Login(user='a', password='b')
print(login_details.as_tuple())
>> ('a', 'b')
```

**EDIT 2**

Note this only works with class attributes and not instance attributes. If you have multiple instances and you change one's user and password then this change will be reflected in the other instances as well.

```
class Login:
    user = None
    password = None

    @classmethod
    def set_or_get(cls, *args):
        if args:
            cls.user, cls.password = args
            return cls
        else:
            return cls.user, cls.password

login_details_a = Login.set_or_get('a', 'b')
login_details_b = Login()

print(login_details_a.set_or_get())
>> ('a', 'b')

print(login_details_b.set_or_get())
>> ('a', 'b')

login_details_b.set_or_get('c', 'd')

print(login_details_a.set_or_get())
>> ('c', 'd')

print(login_details_b.set_or_get())
>> ('c', 'd')
```

Comment: The same method should "set" and "return" user inputs. So this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @shantanuo How should that magic method guess if you are trying to set or get?

Comment: If the username and password is provided then set else return whatever is already known.

Comment: @shantanuo This would only be possible if `username` and `password` are class attributes (not instance attributes).

Comment: I am ok with that. Will that matter if I have a very simple class with a few functions?